# Dog suddenly barking and hiding

Tags: dogs, behavior, health, psychology

My year and half old Rottweiler/German Shepherd has developed a scary behavior recently.

All of a sudden he start barking, runs like mad, then goes and hides in a dark place. When he is in his kennel and at night he is calm and relaxed.

My question is: can sunlight affect his brain like aura in epilepsy, or could he be  suffering from a brain tumor?

Any help from someone with similar experience would be appreciated. It makes me feel sad and helpless to see this.

Comment: One, you will have to add more information. Two, give this information to your vet not us, it seems like it could be serious.

Comment: My Vet has never seen such behavior

Comment: Is there any chance it is dry enough in your home that he moves and gets a static electricity shock? That's what was happening to one of mine.